# Multiplying with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple script, i want to multiply Var a * Var b then Multiply this by Var C with  a set number eg 15.

But it doesn't seem to work?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('input[name="box2"]').keyup(function() {
    var a = $('input[name="box1"]').val();
    var b = $(this).val();
    var c = $(15).val();
    $('input[name="box3"]').val(a * b * c);
});
​
</script>
</head>


<body>
<input name="box1" type="text" /><br />
<input name="box2" type="text" /><br />
<input name="box3" type="text" />
</body>
```

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library. It is JavaScript that will do your multiplication. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `$(15).val()`... if you want an actual number, just use an actual number: `var c = 15;`. You don't need jQuery to create a numeric literal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few changes to do :

```
var a = parseInt($('input[name="box1"]').val(), 10);
var b = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
var c = 15; // really no need to try to build a dom element to get an int
```

Beware never never use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) without specifying the radix (`parseInt("09") is 0...`).

Another problem in your code is that you try to build your jquery collection before the dom is ready. Use this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('input[name="box2"]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('input[name="box1"]').val();
     var b = $(this).val();
     var c = $(15).val();
     $('input[name="box3"]').val(a * b * c);
   });
});
</script>
```

Note that it's also best practice, especially when using jQuery which makes it easy, to have a script element at the end of the body to keep all the javascript that isn't in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Change `var c = $(15).val();` to `var c=15;`

Answer (score 0):

You should parse value which is string to int:

```
var a = parseInt($('input[name="box1"]').val());
```

Comment: parseInt is automatic for multiplication.
Try doing "4"*"5".

Comment: ... by specifying the radix `parseInt(value, 10)`