# jQuery multiplication isn't working for me

Tags: jquery, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply the value inside two divs and put the product in a third, and I'm failing. I tried to follow the methods in [a previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490056/multiplying-with-jquery), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Specifically, I've got "add" and "subtract" controls to change the number of Rows and Columns (to be worked with later). I'm trying to get the number of cells (rows * columns) to update automatically when either of the others is changed.

[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/3/). The code I'm using is:

```
<table id="controls">
<tr><td>Rows:</td><td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="javascript:appendRow()" class="append_row"/><input type="button" value="-" onclick="javascript:deleteRow()" class="delete"/></td><td class="numbers" id="numRows">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Columns:</td><td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="javascript:appendColumn()" class="append_column"/><input type="button" value="-" onclick="javascript:deleteColumn()" class="delete"/></td><td class="numbers" id="numColumns">2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Total cells:</td><td class="numbers" id="rc-product"></td></tr>
</table>

$('#controls').keyup(function(){
var rows_val = $('#numRows').val();
var columns_val = $('#numColumns').val();
$('#rc-product').val( rows_val * columns_val);
});
```

But nothing is displaying. Should I be using parseInt and text()? How?

Comment: have you tried setting breakpoints and seeing if the values are there? have you tried moving the multiplication to outside of the assignment? I would get familiar with a debugger (I use F12 in Chrome) as it makes life much easier in the JS world

Comment: you can use .html or .text but not .val [http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/6/)

Comment: Why are you binding the keyup event there is nothing to write in so that event will not trigger? You should be using `text()` everywhere `val()` is for input fields. The following fiddle works, but I've added a button to perform the calculations http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `click()`, since you're using the mouse, rather than keyboard-keys. Also, `val()` is only relevant to `input` and `textarea` elements. Use `text()`:

```
$('#controls').click(function () {
    var rows_val = parseFloat($('#numRows').text()),
        columns_val = parseFloat($('#numColumns').text());
    $('#rc-product').text(rows_val * columns_val);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gwv2n/9/).

The use of `parseFloat()` converts the string of the text, from the element, into a number that can be used for mathematical operation (or `NaN`, if the string starts with a non-numeric character). `parseInt()` could be used instead, but that limits you to integers, whereas `parseFloat()`, as the name implies, handles floats as well.

To update the total on page-load/document-ready, you could also use `click()` (without an argument) to trigger the click event, which will invoke the click-handler bound previously:

```
$('#controls').click(function () {
    var rows_val = parseFloat($('#numRows').text()),
        columns_val = parseFloat($('#numColumns').text());
    $('#rc-product').text(rows_val * columns_val);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gwv2n/13/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thank you very much! that does the trick. I don't have the rep to upvote you, but I would if I could.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! Of this answer solved your problem, though, consider accepting it as the answer to your question (by checking the tick-mark besides the text). Or, if another answer helped you more, consider accepting that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `keyup` event is triggered when you release a key on the keyboard, so probably this is not what you are looking for. In order to trigger your multiply function when one of your buttons are clicked, you'll need to use the `click` event.

Also, to get or set the inner content of a DOM element you should use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (or [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), if you want to pick the HTML tags inside it too) method instead of `val`.

```
$('#controls').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function() {
    var rows_val = $('#numRows').text();
    var columns_val = $('#numColumns').text();
    $('#rc-product').text(rows_val * columns_val);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/8/

If you want your function to be evaluated in the page load too, so the multiplication result would already be displayed on the page load, you could transform it into a named function and run it on the `$(document).ready` event.

```
function calculate() {
    var rows_val = $('#numRows').text();
    var columns_val = $('#numColumns').text();
    $('#rc-product').text(rows_val * columns_val);    
}

$('#controls').on('click', 'input[type=button]', calculate);
$(document).ready(calculate);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/12/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see what your problem is. You're trying to use $.val() to retrieve the text inside a div. $.val() returns the value attribute of an input element. Using $.text() will fix this.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwv2n/10/

You also need to put all your logic in a document ready function as below:

```
$(function() {
  $('#controls input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    var rows_val = $('#numRows').text();
    var columns_val = $('#numColumns').text();
    $('#rc-product').text( rows_val * columns_val);
    console.log(rows_val, columns_val);
  });
});
```